# Why don't all vampires turn into ashes?

Tags: vampire, blade

In the Blade movie series, vampires turn into ashes when killed (or scratched?) by silver.

In the first movie, Blade was in that vampire nightclub hunting Deacon Frost's friend, Quinn, who got impaled twice by silver yet didn't turn into ashes. Do you need to aim for the heart / brain?

In other scenes some vampire goons turn into ashes when simply being hit (arms, legs) by Blade's silver sword.

Comment: His name is Quinn, btw. The wikia suggests that different houses have different sensitivities, and pureblood vs not pureblood might make a difference as well, but nothing definitive to put in an answer.

Comment: They need to be staked through the heart or have their heads removed.

Comment: I think Quinn is supposed to be a uniquely powerful vampire, and might be able to withstand silver to some degree. Some of other goons are probably human, and not vampires, and would not turn to ash.

Answer (score 4):

In the Blade movies, the only vampires that turned to ash were either stabbed through the heart or decapitated: ["Vampire (Marvel Comics)", *Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_(Marvel_Comics))

Comment: A fan wiki (with no evidence to back it up) is a very poor source of information. Honestly this answer barely rates as a comment.